# How to store 3000+ images for offline use Angular 2

Tags: cordova, angular, local-storage

I am building a cross platform app using Angular 2. Deployment on mobile using Cordova.
I need to store 3000+ images for offline use of the app.
I receive the images in Base64 format.

I will appreciate an advice on the best way to implement this task.

Best,
Ziv

Comment: This should provide the answers you need: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html

Comment: JosiahDaniels - thanks. I read the Cordova documentation but I need advice from a vetren Cordova developer as for the best option to choose.